# Data storage from MAXREFDES100 via BLE

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, mbed

In my graduating project, I would like to stream the data from the MAXREFDES100 board sensors (accelerometer, biopotentials, etc.) via BLE and save it as a file.

1)  The smartphone application provided is intended only to monitor the measurements (meaning, the data is only streamed and not stored)
2) The PC GUI provided works only via COM-port (USB connection)

What can I do in order to store the data that is real-time streamed on a phone storage?

Is there any option to transfer the data directly to the PC via BLE or make the connection via BLE instead of USB?

Is there any open source code to do that? 
If not, do I need to write a script in Android studio for the phone to record the data to the file and to write the script in mbed to the HDK developer board of the MAXREFDES?
I'm new to implications in this field and programs,
Your help would be very appreciated!
Thank you!

Comment: Hi NikaY, Welcome to StackOverflow, Your question is a bit unclear or too-board. please read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) & [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) & Also [topics](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: Hi, I've tried to clarify the question. You are right, it is broad and if it helps I can split it to two different questions.